# MySQL how to avoid duplicate row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, duplicates

I have a little problem with my MySQL table.

Here is how looks my db table:

[image]

How to avoid duplicate row, I want when add new insert if column 'doc' AND 'date' have same values just replace them?

[image]

[image]

I will be very grateful if someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "just replace them"?

Comment: If columns `doc` and `date` have the same values you dont need to do anything. There are only 3 columns in that table, the only other is the `id`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I add new image in post. I hope this will clear my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a unique index to the doc and date columns, then use on duplicate update

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, doc, date)
values ('id','doc','date')
on duplicate key update date = 'date'
```

or whatever you need.  You can specify multiple columns such as...

```
on duplicate key update date = 'date, doc = 'doc', etc...
```

**EDIT**

If doc and date are not keys, and you do not want an index on them, I think the only way is to pull query first to see if a row exists with doc and date both equal to your new doc and date values.  If row exists, update it - if it does not exist, insert new.

Comment: Not what he asked for at all __`if column 'doc' AND 'date' have same values`__ they are not keys

Comment: I want if i have 'doc': 528 and 'date': 30/09/2015 but not be able to add 'doc': 528 and 'date': 30/09/2015 (with diff. id), but I can add that 'doc': 529 and 'date': 30/09/2015 or 'doc': 528 and 'date': 29/09/2015.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to insert into a table and the table uses an AI for it's primary key and you don't explicitly make one, you will always make a duplicate.

The "ON DUPLICATE KEY" function cannot be extended to an "ON DUPLICATE FIELD" function.

Your only real solution is a code change as Phil says. Do something like:

```
SELECT id
FROM mytable
WHERE doc = '$doc' AND
date = '$date'
```

Then if there are any results, you can either do the insert with the explicit id, or you can just ignore it.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, doc, date)
values ('$id','$doc','$date')
```